# Hat dialog won't open when clicking a hat in top while already viewing my profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, winter-bash-2013

Clicking a hat in the top bar achieved hats list redirects to the profile page, opening the hats dialog and choose the hat, ready to be confirmed. Superb!

While I was still checking on my existing hats I got a new hat. In a reflex I clicked the hat in the top bar notification but... nothing happened. Well, the URL changed to `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard#winter-bash-[id]` but since it didn't trigger page reload the dialog did not open and I had to do that manually. (the horror!)

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Nice double hat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that was annoying. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, was it also reported before in chat?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure. I did notice it myself though, and there also was a [dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212007/winter-bash-box-link-not-working-properly) here on meta.

Comment: Cheers, didn't notice it was asked again. (why not mark the dupe as status-completed too?)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be consensus whether dupes should get status tags or not. I'm in the "no" camp :)

Comment: Fair enough but you know that most likely at some point someone will flag it and a mod will retag, right? :)