# Winter Bash Box link not working properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, winter-bash-2013

I tried to click the recently earned hat in Winter Bash popup box, but it is not working and no action to that click. Note it is working in Stack Overflow, but not in [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you are already on your profile page of the same site. It is not opening the link (anchor) when you are already there.

E.g. If I am on my MSO profile page (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187824/hims056), I won't be able to open any hats earned in MSO from the top bar. But if I open the link in new tab it will open the popup with that hat. So this is not a Drupal only issue.

This need to be fixed.

Comment: thanks for pointing the exact issue!!!, but it looks not an answer to my post, feel free to edit my post and add the details.

Comment: @Bala: Pointing out the exact issue **is** fine in Meta sites.